# How to make an expander control hover over the next element?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, expander

In my setup exemplified below, I didn't notice until recently that when the list of elements listed in the expander grows (so that the length of it exceeds the length of the buttons in the panel next to it), it doesn't hover over the data grid, as intuitively expected. Instead, it pushes it down which makes the whole GUI to appear jumpy vertically.

```
<StackPanel>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel>
      <Expander>...</Expander>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
      <Button ... /><Button ... /><Button ... />
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <DataGrid ... />
  </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

One way to fix this is to put everything in the same cell in a grid and add the expander last. However, that seems to me inappropriate on several levels. Instead, I'd prefer to force expander to expand touchlessly **above** the other controls. It should affect the layout but only its size from the folded state. The expansion should not affect the layout at all.

How can I tell the stupid expander not to be so pushy?

Comment: Have you considered using a `Popup` or `ComboBox` instead of an Expander?

Comment: @Sphinxxx Yes. It needs to be the expander control for several reasons. In fact, at the moment, it's be easier to do it the ugly way (put everything in the same cell in a grid) than fooling around changing the expander. I've got some functionality baked in there and starting to re-develop makes my skin crawl... Too afraid of oopsies, and gotchas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For reference, let's number the `StackPanel` elements from your original XAML:

```
<StackPanel #1>
    <StackPanel #2 Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel #3>
            <Expander>...</Expander>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel #4>
            <Button ... /><Button ... /><Button ... />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel #5 Orientation="Horizontal">
        <DataGrid ... />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

A `StackPanel` when oriented horizontally will set its height to that of its *tallest* child, and when oriented vertically will set its height to the *sum of all* of its children's heights.

When you expand the `Expander` control, you increase its height, and therefore you increase the height of its container (#3). This in turn may or may not increase the height of #3's parent container (#2) depending on whether the expander becomes larger in height than the stack panel containing the buttons (#4).

To achieve the effect you seem to be after, you can either use a `Grid` as already discussed in the question and other answer, or you can use a `Canvas` element like so:

```
<Window x:Class="..."
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Panel.ZIndex="1">
            <Canvas Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Expander}">
                <Expander x:Name="Expander" Header="Header" Background="Yellow">
                    <StackPanel Background="Aqua">
                        <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander>
            </Canvas>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="Button1" />
                <Button Content="Button2" />
                <Button Content="Button3" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Some more text" Background="LimeGreen" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The canvas as used here allows the expander control to "escape" the boundaries of the container. To get the expander control to "float" above the element directly underneath it (the `TextBlock` in this example), the `Panel.ZIndex` attached property is used. We also need to bind the width of the canvas to the width of the expander as the canvas will not size itself based on its children.

Here's how it looks when the expander is collapsed:

[image]

And how it looks when it is expanded:

[image]

(Forgive the horrible colours, they are just so you can see where the control boundaries are).

Comment: The colors are great! One can clearly see what is what. I wonder if this is the intended purpose of the canvas control, though. I was under the impression that its purpose was to draw on...

Comment: @KonradViltersten The purpose of the WPF `Canvas` is to layout its children at specific coordinates, it doesn't have anything to do with drawing at all really. It also has the useful property of allowing its children to "escape" its bounds by default (ie. it doesn't clip its children to its own bounds). Therefore it is often used when you need an "overlapping" effect. The only other built-in control that has similar layering possibilities is the `Grid`, but that is a more "heavyweight" panel.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Think of the `Canvas` in this case as being a bit like `position: relative;` in CSS, in that the canvas is the layout "slot" and its child elements are positioned relative to the canvas but can end-up overlaying other elements outside of the bounds of the canvas.

Comment: Cool stuff :) Is there a way to let the Expander "flow" over the containing Window boundaries too? I packed my Expander in a Usercontrol hoping the Panel.ZIndex set in the UC would be enough, as it seems, I had to set the ZIndexes in the containing Grid/Panel too, to achieve "on Top".

Comment: @dba I think all WPF controls are clipped to their parent window's bounds. You could try using a Popup control, which is basically its own window, but then you might run into focus issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is such a prominent post when you look for answers for this kind of problem, I feel it should be mentioned that a `<popup>` can work very well in this situation.

Place a `<popup>` inside the content of the expander and you will achieve the same sort of functionality with a much simpler Xaml layout.

Edit: I've explored this option and there's a caveat... Popups are built int to go above OTHER WINDOWS! You'll need to either program the popup to close when the window loses focus or override the template a bit.  This can also be easily googled.

Comment: Woah... 1 day, 1 week, 1 month and 7 years later - answers still coming in.   :)